# Can Visual Studio Intellisense display options for formating values?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

I attached an image to show exactly what I mean.
Is there a way to make Visual Studio to display that dropdown menu with the different options for formating?

Thanks in Advance

[image]

Comment: Intellisense doesn't have an option like that. Sounds like a good idea for a VS extension though. I'm not sure if there are any existing tools that provide that feature.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I was really trying to find something about it, but I couldn't. Maybe because I don't know how to exactly call that dropdown menu there, or because it just doesn't exist in visual studio. Thanks again

Comment: @41686d6564 Can I ask you something else? I don't want to make another post for it. In XAML (Xamarin in this case), is there a way to see what arguments a class can get? For example, I write AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="". Is there a way to display what arguments can be taken here other than using google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can Visual Studio Intellisense display options for formating values?

**I am afraid that you cannot get what you want so far on VS.**

**Actually**, **VS Intellisense** does not have such function and do not have different formatting options in the drop-down box just as your picture shows.

**Also**, I cannot find any VS extensions to implement this function.

So if you still want this feature on VS, I suggest you could suggest a feature on our [User Voice Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=8).

[image]

**Besides**, when you finish it, you could also share your idea ticket here and anyone who is interested in it will vote it so that it will get more **Team's** attention.

Comment: I'll try later on to raise the ticket. Thanks for your answer and for letting me know I could actually ask them to implement it.